# I want to show the text "Menu" on hover over the hamburger (fontawsome icon)

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I am new to coding so need help placing the text "Menu" when hovering over the hamburger item on this page: https://era.org.au/ I am hoping that this can easily be done with some additional css.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following code in your stylesheet:

```
.dropbtn.fa.fa-bars:hover::before {
    content: "Menu";
}
```